# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xppSite' when gunicorn and application are configured in different locations

Tags: django, gunicorn

I am getting this error and suspect failure could be due to my folder structure. That means virtual env folder is at:

```
WorkingDirectory=/home/xxxx/xxagent
ExecStart=/home/xxxx/xxagent/virtualenv/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile - \
          --workers 3 \
          --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
            xppSite.wsgi:application
```

and application files are at different location:

```
/home/xxxx/xxagent/workspace/deploy/xppSite/wsgi.py
```

In such situation, how do I fix this error:

```
Feb 03 05:52:30 ubuntu-sfo3-01 gunicorn[99254]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
Feb 03 05:52:30 ubuntu-sfo3-01 gunicorn[99254]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1140, in _find_and_load_unlocked
Feb 03 05:52:30 ubuntu-sfo3-01 gunicorn[99254]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xppSite'
Feb 03 05:52:30 ubuntu-sfo3-01 gunicorn[99254]: [2024-02-03 05:52:30 +0000] [99254] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 99254)
Feb 03 05:52:30 ubuntu-sfo3-01 gunicorn[99252]: [2024-02-03 05:52:30 +0000] [99252] [ERROR] Worker (pid:99253) exited with code 3
Feb 03 05:52:30 ubuntu-sfo3-01 gunicorn[99252]: [2024-02-03 05:52:30 +0000] [99252] [ERROR] Worker (pid:99254) was sent SIGTERM!
Feb 03 05:52:30 ubuntu-sfo3-01 gunicorn[99252]: [2024-02-03 05:52:30 +0000] [99252] [ERROR] Shutting down: Master
Feb 03 05:52:30 ubuntu-sfo3-01 gunicorn[99252]: [2024-02-03 05:52:30 +0000] [99252] [ERROR] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
Feb 03 05:52:30 ubuntu-sfo3-01 systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=3/NOTIMPLEMENTED
Feb 03 05:52:30 ubuntu-sfo3-01 systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Thanks in advance**strong text**